The Berry-Esseen CLT Bound on a Shrinking Interval
Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables. In my case, suppose all the moments of the distribution of $X_1$ are finite (this is not generally needed but in my case let's take the strongest assumptions). Let $\mu$ be the mean and $\sigma^2$ the variance. Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$ and $\Phi$ the c.d.f. of the standard normal. It is well-known that, by the Berry-Esseen theorem,
$$ \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |\mathbb{P}[ \frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} <x ] - \Phi(x)| = O(n^{-1/2})  $$ and one can even show that this bound is optimal.
However, what if we are approximating the probability on a specific interval whose size is shrinking at speed $n^{-1/2}$, for instance, for some $c>0$, we want to bound
$$  |\mathbb{P}[ -cn^{-1/2} < \frac{S_n - n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} < cn^{-1/2} ] - \int_{-cn^{-1/2}}^{cn^{-1/2}} e^{-t^2/2} dt |. $$
Does this expression still decay at speed $O(n^{-1/2})$, or perhaps the convergence is faster with maybe $O(n^{-1})$ or even $o(n^{-1})$?

Your expression decays at rate $O(n^{-3/2})$. To prove this, we can use the Edgeworth series.
Let $F_n$ denote the cumulative density function of $(S_n-n\mu)/(\sigma\sqrt n)$. For each $m\ge 1$, let $\kappa_m$ be the $m^\text{th}$ cumulant of $X_1$, and let $\lambda_m=\kappa_m/\sigma^m$ be the normalized cumulant. The Edgeworth series gives a finer description of the rate of convergence of $F_n$ to the standard normal cdf, $\Phi$. For all $x\in \mathbb R$,
$$
F_n(x)=\Phi(x)-\frac1{n^{1/2}}\Big(\tfrac16\lambda_3 \Phi^{(3)}(x)\Big)+\frac1{n}\Big(\tfrac1{24}\lambda_4 \Phi^{(4)}(x)+\tfrac1{72}\lambda_3^2\Phi^{(6)}(x)\Big)+O(n^{-3/2})
$$
$\Phi^{(k)}$ is the $k^\text{th}$ derivative of $\Phi$.
Let $\delta=cn^{-1/2}$. Applying the Edgeworth series to both $F_n(\delta)$ and $F_n(-\delta)$, we get
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
F_n(\delta)-F_n(-\delta)
&= \Phi(\delta)-\Phi(-\delta)
\\
&\phantom{=}-\frac{\lambda_3}{6n^{1/2}}\Big(\Phi^{(3)}(\delta)-\Phi^{(3)}(-\delta)\Big)
\\
&\phantom{=}+\frac{\lambda_4}{24n}\Big(\Phi^{(4)}(\delta)-\Phi^{(4)}(-\delta)\Big)+\frac{\lambda_3^2}{72n}\Big(\Phi^{(6)}(\delta)-\Phi^{(6)}(-\delta)\Big)
\\
&\phantom{=}+O(n^{-3/2 })
\\
\end{align}
Now, for any smooth function $g$, the Taylor approximation of $g$ around $0$ gives
$$
g(\delta)-g(-\delta)=2\delta\cdot g'(0)+O(\delta^2)=2cn^{-1/2}\cdot g'(0)+O(n^{-1}).
$$
Applying this, and noting that $\Phi^{(4)}(0)$ happens to be zero, we get
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
&\phantom{=}F_n(\delta)-F_n(-\delta)-(\Phi(\delta)-\Phi(-\delta))
\\&=
-\frac{\lambda_3}{3n^{}}\cancelto{0}{\Phi^{(4)}(0)}
+\frac{\lambda_4}{12n^{3/2}}\Phi^{(5)}(0)
+\frac{\lambda_3^2}{36n^{3/2}}\Phi^{(7)}(0)+O(n^{-3/2})
\\&= O(n^{-3/2})
\end{align}
$$
We have shown that $F_n(\delta)-F_n(-\delta)-(\Phi(\delta)-\Phi(-\delta))=O(n^{-3/2})$, as claimed.
You were specifically asking about the probability of $(S_n-\sigma n^{-1/2})/(\sigma n^{1/2})$ being in a shrinking neighborhood of zero. You can also ask about being in a shrinking neighborhood of a general point $x\in \mathbb R$. In this case, the difference between the actual probability and the standard normal approximation only decreases as $O(n^{-1})$, because $\Phi^{(4)}(x)$ is not zero in general.
$$
F_n(x+\delta)-F_n(x-\delta)-(\Phi(x+\delta)-\Phi(x-\delta))=\frac1{n^{}}\Big(\tfrac13\lambda_3 \Phi^{(4)}(x)\Big)+O(n^{-3/2})
$$
However, there are special cases where you get a decay of $O(n^{-3/2})$  for a neighborhood of every $x\in \mathbb R$. If $\lambda_3=0$, which occurs for random variables symmetric around their mean, then the $O(n^{-1})$ term disappears, and we get a rate of $O(n^{-3/2})$.
